# PHP & SQL | JOIN table with same field | Result not giving me the field I want

Tags: php, sql, join

I have 2 Tables, Order & Member.
I need to show some records in Order and who made that order, so I use sql JOIN.

However both Tables have this field called "status" (same spelling).
I need to display the Order.status, but my result is giving me Member.status.

Am I going to have to, instead of using SELECT *, list all the fields that I want in order to get Order.status? Or is there another simpler way? There are many fields I want to display, so it will be quite long.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM orders INNER JOIN member ON orders.customerid=member.sno";
...
echo $row[status];
```

Do I have to do:

```
$query = "SELECT order.A, order.B, order.status, member.status, member.X ... FROM orders INNER JOIN member ON orders.customerid=member.sno";
```

Kind Regards

Comment: Simply [alias](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) the conflicting column names, `SELECT order.status AS order_status`, etc. Be aware that you can't alias `*`, so you'll have to specify the alias for each conflicting column. You _can_ do `SELECT *, order.status AS order_status` etc. That said, in general it's good practice to not `*` but be specific about the columns you select.

Comment: Thank you, I will use SELECT *, order.status AS order_status